# Converting data:image from base64 to JPEG in Python

Tags: python, image, base64

From the client's POST submission, we are successfully receiving an image in the following format, `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/....` and an image file is being generated by the following code:

```
@app.route('/submission', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submission():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        raw_image = request.form['file']
        #Problem Starts Here
        # this doesn't work either: 
        # raw_image = raw_image.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/", '');
        with open(UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST+'/image.jpeg', 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(base64.decodebytes(raw_image))
        #Problem Ends Here
        return jsonify(request.form)
        
    return render_template('submission.html')
```

However, the image cannot be opened as it's an "Invalid or Unsupported Format". I'm trying to improve the conversion process so it will produce a viewable JPEG image.

#### Beginning of `raw_image`:

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCADwAUADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAgIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABQYEBwIDCAEACf/EAEwQAAEDAwMCBAQEAwUFBQQLAAECAxEABAUGEiExQQcTUWEIInGBFDKRoRVCUiOxwdHwJGJyouEJFjOSwhdDgvEmU2ODk7LDxNLU4v/EABsBAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAA`...

Comment: can you please, print the beginning of `raw_image` and `image.jpeg` file ?

Comment: I've added the `raw_image` but upon closer inspection, it looks like the file being created is empty and is 0 bytes.

Comment: I think you need to pass only the stuff following `base64,` to `decodebytes()`.

Comment: In case unclear, I mean you should pass `/9j....` onwards to `decodebytes()`, but don't search for `/9j` because it will be different if you get a PNG file, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your data, and decoded it, it looks quite close to the JPEG header I took from the real file (picture below). Don't see any problem, except, you have to start decoding from `/9j/4AA...` onwards.

```
>>> a = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCADwAUADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAgIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABQYEBwIDCAEACf/EAEwQAAEDAwMCBAQEAwUFBQQLAAECAxEABAUGEiExQQcTUWEIInGBFDKRoRVCUiOxwdHwJGJyouEJFjOSwhdDgvEmU2ODk7LDxNLU4v/EABsBAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAA'
>>> base64.b64decode(a)
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x03\x02\x02\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x04\x03\x03\x04\x05\x08\x05\x05
```

This is a hex dump from the real JPEG picture of mine.

[image]

You have to remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, but don't go beyond that -- this will break the image data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I get an error on `base64.decodebytes(raw_image)` : `TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str`. I tried to switch to `.decodestring()` but received the same error. Is my use of `raw_image = raw_image.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '');` ruining the data?

Comment: @dadiletta please, carefully read my answer. if you have a string, use `base64.b64decode()`